# MongoDB not updating while posted new data from react frontend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb

**CreateCategory.jsx**

```
const handleCreate = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      try{
        const categoryData = new FormData()
        categoryData.append("name", name)
        categoryData.append("photo", photo)

        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/category", categoryData)
        if(data.success){
          toast.success("Product created successfully")
          navigate("/categories")
        }
      } catch(error){
          console.log(error)
          toast.error("Something went wrong")
      }
  }
```

**controllers/category.js**

```
export const createCategory = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const { name } = req.fields
        const { photo } = req.files  

        if (!name) {
            return res.status(401).send({ message: "Name is required" });
        }

        const existingCategory = await categoryModel.findOne({ name })
        if(existingCategory){
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: "Category already exists" 
            })
        }

        const category = await new categoryModel({
            name,
            slug: slugify(name)
        })
        if(photo){
            category.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(photo.path)
            category.photo.contentType = photo.type
        }
        await category.save()

        res.status(201).send({
            success: true,
            message: "New category created",
            category
        })
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            error, 
            message: "Error in adding category"
        })
    }
}
```

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'
import authRoutes from "./routes/authRoutes.js"
import categoryRoutes from "./routes/categoryRoutes.js"
import productRoutes from "./routes/productRoutes.js"

dotenv.config()


const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(cookieParser())

const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        //ecommerce-store
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI); 
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/api/category", categoryRoutes)
app.use("/api/product", productRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    connectDB()
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
})
```

[image: The MongoDB cannot show all the collection data]

When I am trying to post a new form data from the react frontend page, the form can be submitted and the page could also display the new data on the main page. However, the MongoDB database could not show all the data while the total documents updated but the results still remain unchanged. Is it because the size limitation?

Answer (score 1):

After create new Data for category, you can see updated datalist in main page.
this means that you database is already updated.
I think you are using some tools for db management like navicat...
So to see result of updated data, refresh in db management tool.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).